# Clickable hyperlinks in widget textview

Tags: android

For some reason after I made textviews clickable and have autolink set to web it still doesn't open a browser. Do I need to use an event listener then handle it that way? Or is it something simple that I am overlooking? I'll start by posting the textview XML code :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html. check the link

Comment: Unfortunately widgets have to use remoteViews which is quite limited. It cant use findViewByID

Comment: you can try clickable span. not sure it will work for your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use an onclick event to handle the browser launching. I'm still an complete amateur at android programming so I got the information from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/L9I_67jy94o):

```
// Register an onClickListener
            Intent broswerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.cnn.com"));
            broswerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            broswerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser",

            "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(), 0, broswerIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code was written about year ago but I think it should work:

```
TextView result_view = new TextView(this);
result_view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=" + linkUrl + ">"+ linkTitle + "</a>"));
result_view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for activities. RemoteViews do not have access to the method setMovementMethod. This might be written up as impossible until an update or something.

Comment: I don't have experience with RemoteView but maybe you should use Intent.ACTION_VIEW in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines .

```
final TextView input = new TextView(this);
            alert.setView(input);
            input.setText(Html.fromHtml("www.google.com")); // you can pass your strings over there. 
            Linkify.addLinks(input, Linkify.ALL); 
            alert.setMessage("Test");
```

Hope this helps you.